# Are desktop programs daemons?

Tags: unix

I am a beginner for programming, so I am sorry if this question sounds stupid...

I am reading a book on Unix. I am wondering whether the programs that run on my desktop, such as iTunes or Skype, are regarded as deamons. I am confused because if I type `ps` in the terminal, all that I see is the bash kernel, unless I utilize the option `-e`. This seems to suggest that iTunes and Skype are just like other daemons running in the background.

However, conceptually a daemon should not use any input from the user, but I think iTunes and Skype do need input from the user...

What am I getting wrong? Please help, thank you!!

Comment: In the classic unix sense, a daemon is a process that detached from its (controlling) tty. (=terminal), allowing it to continue without user interaction. For modern desktop-like unices, this criterium becomes rather vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programs like iTunes and Skype are not really daemons, precisely because they do interact with the user and can display to the screen.  However, they are not tied to a terminal session either.

They are independent processes; they run in the background until you bring them to the foreground.  They may have daemons of their own (iTunes has a helper program that is a daemon).  But the main UI for Skype or iTunes is not a daemon.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. So is there any way the terminal can interact with or monitor those desktop applications? Say if I want to kill a irresponsive iTunes from the terminal.

Comment: You can find the program via options to `ps`, obtaining the process ID or PID.  You can then run `kill $PID` or `kill -1 $PID` (sending SIGTERM and SIGHUP respectively; equivalently, `kill -TERM $PID` and `kill -HUP $PID`).  I recommend going gently first; the program may be able handle these cleanly.  If neither of those jolts the recalcitrant process back to life, then you start going for the kill, leading up to `kill -9 $PID` (or `kill -KILL $PID`).  If for some reason you don't own the process, you may have to use `sudo` or `su` to gain root privileges to send the death threats.